# Desired_capabilities not working in Robot Framework

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to run robot scripts on IE browser. I try to open the browser as shown in the code below.I cannot access the security tab because of corporate rules and hence I am trying to set it through the script. However, this does not work and it gives me the error

WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.

```
Open Browser To Main Page
Open browser    ${WELCOME URL}    ${BROWSER}     desired_capabilities=ignoreProtectedModeSettings:True  
Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
Home Page Should Be Open
```

Please let me know if you think that I am missing something or have got the syntax wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try below **Capability** and let me know what happens,

```
InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true
```

It should not through the **Selenium exception**.